# Vim key map in jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

When editing a .py file with jupyter, I have the option to choose the vim key map in the Edit dropdown menu (alongside the Default, emacs and Sublime text options). However, when opening a notebook file (.ipynb), I do not have this option. Is there a way to activate this?

I know there are some third party plugins out there, but they don't seem to support block select mode and other more advanced options like regex commands.

Not sure it matters, but I'm opening my notebooks with the Anaconda navigator.

Comment: the question is not about vim editor. It is another editor, which provides some vim-like functions. You should not expect it to become vim after all.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the edit. The vim-like functions that are available when editing .py files within jupyter are pretty close to "real" vim, unlike when editing .ipynb files... hence my hope something more exists out there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this plugin [lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding](http://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding).

Attached screenshot to get an idea about the plugin:
[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks. I saw that one but inferred from the movie it wasn't what I was looking for. But I may be wrong. Does it allow to input regex commands, block selection (ctrl-v), etc?

Comment: Yes, It does allow.

Comment: Please note that the author of this awesome plugin has moved on to a different job and isn't maintaining the code - see announcement in the github repo.  As of this comment, the plugin seems to  be alive and well though!