# How do I install Vim key bindings in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: vim, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646907/vim-key-map-in-jupyter-notebook) answer. I went to the github page that the answer talks about and installed jupyter notebook extensions too. I execute this code on anaconda command shell like the [github page](https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding) asks me to:

```
# You may need the following to create the directoy
mkdir -p $(jupyter --data-dir)/nbextensions
# Now clone the repository
cd $(jupyter --data-dir)/nbextensions
git clone https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding vim_binding
chmod -R go-w vim_binding
```

However, the first line with mkdir throws an error:
`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`
Since I do not know how these commands work or what they do, can someone please help find a workaround?

Comment: These are instructions for unix based systems. There are steps for windows in the github issues, e.g. : https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding/issues/98#issuecomment-346543429